# Cannot JSON.parse serverless event.body

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I’ve been working on a simple function with the serverless framework that gets some data in a http POST, does some analysis and sends the results back. I got it working locally on my machine using serverless-offline but when it comes to deploying it I’m getting an error parsing the event.body.

Logging out the event.body it’s a string that looks like this:

```
----------------------------267253304929569989286258
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

TEST
----------------------------267253304929569989286258--
```

so it makes sense that the parse is failing but I have no idea why this error it happening.
Any suggestions? I’ve tried a bunch of different things but am completely stumped.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't JSON.parse that event.body cause it isn't JSON. It looks like whatever POSTed that data is using a multipart form POST style request rather than sending JSON. How are you invoking the HTTP POST?

Comment: So this is using postman. Invoking the http request with axios seems to give a normal looking event.body.

Comment: In Postman, when doing the POST, in the Body section change the content type options. Select the "raw" radio button, then select "JSON (application/json)" in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after a lot of debugging noticed 2 important things:

1.When the content type is **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** you might need to parse the data in a different way:

```
const qs = require('querystring');

module.exports.run = async event => {
    try {
        const data = qs.parse(event.body);
        console.info('DATA:', data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e.message);
    }
}
```

2.When the **Content-Type** of the request is **multipart/form-data** the parsing will be even more complicated. I will suggest extra dependency to parse it like [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty) or any other of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Brian Winant! I am putting the answer here as a screenshot so it's clearer. In Postman, do the following:

[image]

AWS Lambda would return `event.body` as encoded query strings if the content-type is `x-www-urlencoded`. To have it return a JSON string you can then parse, send JSON data and set content-type as `application/json`.